# Is it possible to acquire the accent of a foreign language at home?(So i mean by not living in the specific country where the language is spoken)

Tags: second-lang-acquisition

I'm a European non-native english speaker with a fairly high level of fluency(my vocabulary is pretty close to the vocab of a native speaker). Since I've been learning English, my goal has always been to reach native level in it, so that also implies sounding like one. My question is that "Is it possible to acquire a native like accent by not living in the specific country? If so, what's the way to do it? I've heard about bunch of bullsh*t such as people gaining a native like accent by watching television, but I don't believe in these kind of things. Actually, my accent doesn't have influences from my native tongue, because I've eliminated it to the point that people from my country, who speak english can't hear that I'm a non-native english speaker! However, the problem is that I don't have a straight British or American accent. It's like a mixture of the two(Once an American person told me that if I wouldn't have told her my origins, she would think I'm British). So, I would like to have either a straight British or a straight American accent. How am I supposed to do that? I can read phonetics pretty well and I understand linguistics. Should I learn the phonology of one of the dialects? I've also used the application called "Elsa Speak", and it did help, but it didn't give me a straight American accent.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on ELL or Language Learning, as it is not about linguistics, but migrating there doesn't seem possible (for me).

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering this question with full disclosure that my only expertise on this topic is my own effort to acquire a native Lithuanian accent.  I'm Lithuanian American and the American accent in my spoken Lithuanian actually hurts my ears. I feel sorry for any native speaker unlucky enough to have to endure it.  My strategy is to use highly focused active listening whenever I hear Lithuanian spoken, primarily through online TV and radio.  I'm developing a real appreciation for the beauty of the language, and I think it's making a real difference in my own speech.  I've very much bought into the neuroplasticity thing, and am convinced that active listening optimally engages both auditory and speech centers in the brain. In any case, I don't think there's a better way to master an accent than to really listen to/hear it and leave the heavy lifting to the superintelligent wetware we all have between the ears.